# Using RDM6300 and RC522 at once

Tags: esp32, rfid

I want to use both RDM6300 and RC522 at a single .ino code at once. But whenever I try them both, only one of them works. How to get the both working?
[Dev envt. ESP32 Dev module]

```cpp
// LIBRARY ADDITION HERE
#include <SPI.h>
#include <rdm6300.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

// PIN DEFINITIONS HERE
#define RC522_RST_PIN        22
#define RC522_SS_PIN          21 
#define RDM6300_RX_PIN        5

// PIN DEFINITIONS
MFRC522 mfrc522(RC522_SS_PIN, RC522_RST_PIN);
Rdm6300 rdm6300;

void setup() {

  // LIBRARY INITIALTIONS
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();
  delay(4);               // added this delay cus mc is slower than we expected. It takes some time to start the initiation
  rdm6300.begin(RDM6300_RX_PIN);
  delay(5);
}

unsigned long getID522() {

  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return 0;
  }
  unsigned long hex_num;
  hex_num =  mfrc522.uid.uidByte[0] << 24;
  hex_num += mfrc522.uid.uidByte[1] << 16;
  hex_num += mfrc522.uid.uidByte[2] <<  8;
  hex_num += mfrc522.uid.uidByte[3];
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  return hex_num;
}

void loop() {  

  if(mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    unsigned long uid = getID522();
    if(uid != 0){
      Serial.println(uid);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("aaaaaaaaa");

  if (rdm6300.get_new_tag_id()) {
    Serial.println(rdm6300.get_tag_id(), HEX);
    Serial.println("ydfutfcfygfigi");
    Serial.println(rdm6300.get_new_tag_id());
  }

  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: please copy and paste the content of the serial monitor into your question

Comment: read the answer here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/92291/using-mfrc522-along-with-other-inputsbluetooth-keypad